# C2780 error when using variadic function

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I just tried to use a C++11 variadic function template in VS2013. The function should take a variable number of containers (QLists in my case) that carries variable datatypes. These lists should be converted into lists of strings.

This is the simplified function where `Convert()` is a function taking a QList and returning a QStringList:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> void ConvertLists(QList<QStringList>& converted, T c, Args... args)
{ 
   converted.append(Convert(c));
   ConvertLists(converted, args...); // error C2780 expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
QList<int> a;
QList<CATID> b;
QList<double> c;

QList<QStringList> converted;
ConvertLists(converted, a, b, c);
qDebug() << converted;
```

As you can see in the commented line I am getting a compiler error where the function template recurses. I thought I understand how variadic templates are used but obviously I am missing something.

What is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more overload where the recursion can stop:

```
template <typename T>
void ConvertLists(QList<QStringList>& converted, T&& c)
{ 
   converted.append(Convert(std::forward<T>(c)));
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void ConvertLists(QList<QStringList>& converted, T&& c, Args&&... args)
{ 
   converted.append(Convert(std::forward<T>(c)));
   ConvertLists(converted, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You may also try the following single-function solution:

```
template <typename... Args>
void ConvertLists(QList<QStringList>& converted, Args&&... args)
{ 
   converted.append({ Convert(std::forward<Args>(args))... });
}
```